# WXWidgets TextCtrl or RichTextCtrl

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm using wxWidgets for a log window of a piece of software which runs for many hours. The log can accumulate 10,000's of entries. Does the community have a suggestion for how not to have the GUI thread choke for many seconds when updating a textctrl or richtextctrl with this many lines? I'm open to using either control type but richtext is preferable to I can highlight warnings or errors.

It's currently set to readonly, so undo, redo, paste, etc are not active. I'm currently freezing and thawing it before and after adding content.

In a test case, I add 10000 lines to the text control with a freeze and thaw before and after. This operation still takes over a minute. Are these text controls simply incapable of handling long content?

Comment: Display most recent N amount of records in the text control; write the others to a file.  You could customize the control to scroll from a file (in either direction).

Comment: A minute is too much. There's something weird in your code. Can you post it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your display is like a log, where each "line" is it's own entry, try using the `wxListCtrl` in "virtual mode".  Basically, you maintain the data in your own control (a vector, array, whatever works) and the control asks you for only the data that is currently visible.

Inherit `wxListCtrl` with your own class and implement `OnGetItem`.  When a row is visible, your derived control will have this method called for each row (and each column if you implement multiple columns) and you provide it with the data for that row, accessed directly from your array (list, vector, whatever).

More information is available in the wxWidgets docs here: http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_list_ctrl.html#a92370967f97215e6068326645ee76624

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion to use `wxListCtrl` in @avariant answer is a good one, however a `wxTextCtrl` with `wxTE_RICH` style should still be capable of appending 10000 lines in well less than a minute if you freeze/thaw it before/after. I'd be curious to know if you can reproduce the problem in the text sample included with wxWidgets (which already has a menu item doing something like this) and, if so, which wxWidgets port do you use.